# Using atomic types in "wrapper" classes

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I'm new to C++ atomic types and am trying to convert some serial code to a multithreaded version.

1) I have several classes that are basically aliases for machine-types but with associated functions and overloaded operators that allow me to treat those types as if they are something more complicated e.g.:

```
class myClass{
    atomic_ullong x;
public:
    void myClassFunc(atomic_ullong mask){x &= mask;}
    bool operator < (const myClass &in){ return (x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00) <  (in.x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00);}
};
```

Will simply declaring the class members and function parameters as their atomic type equivalents, as I have above, be enough?  Or will wrapping x as a "myClass" force me to start using mutexes and such?

2) If this works, in a few cases I have more complicated code with more than one class member.  In these cases, if those members are all fundamental machine-types (ints and such) can I do the same trick and maintain all the advantages of atomic types?

Of course I can restructure my code here, but the explicit classes keeps it much more simple and keeps me from accidentally doing something to the stored data elements that I shouldn't.

Not that it matters, but I do my debug compiling in Visual Studio 2008 and production compiling in GCC.  I'm downloading VC2019 as we speak for C++11 and higher support.  Previously I've used the Boost libraries for multithreaded apps.

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting at. What kind of MT code will you write? Why even bother with atomics?

Comment: Also, prefer non member operators where applicable.

Comment: 1) maybe, maybe not. Atomic datatypes, by themselves, do not guarantee that any code that uses them will be automatically, 100% money-back guarantee, thread-safe. Atomic datatypes are just one of the tools that can be used to implement thread-safe code. Sometimes using them eliminates the need for mutexes. Sometimes you still need to use mutexes together with atomic objects for other reasons. As such, the rest of your questions are predicated on 1), and since 1) cannot be answered, the rest of your questions are moot.

Comment: Hi curiousguy, the code is used for economic analysis and I am scaling it up for multithreading.  Gazillions of simple operations are performed on elements of a huge datastructure.  Each thread is responsible for calculating results from a portion of that datastructure, but there are no clean mathematical "breaks" or "demarcations" in the data.  At the "edges" the data assigned to different threads interact mathematically.  So multiple threads may want to manipulate the same data at the same time.  Hence the requirement for atomicity.

Comment: Pro tip: use @curiousguy to notify a user that you are replying to them

Comment: The function argument `mask` doesn't need to be atomic.

Comment: @user11623233 No offense but you don't seem to know what you need and what atomics are for. The very vague description you give absolutely does **not** justify atomics anymore than another specific design. Atomic are seldom needed and *the probability that the best (or even any) solution to a problem is to use atomics everywhere is near zero*.

Comment: Writing thread-safe code is not a matter of applying some magic dust to existing code.  Code is thread-safe because it was **designed** that way. Adapting existing code to a multi-threaded application means redesigning the code, and then rewriting it to match the new design. It's far more difficult than it might seem at first glance.

Comment: On the other hand, not all programs need to be made multi thread. They can run mono thread - and let multi core computer run other programs at the same time. Mono thread doesn't mean other cores stay there doing nothing!

Answer (score 2):

If you read then write, that isn't atomic with naive operations.

If you write to two atomic values, the two writes together are not atomic.

In general, taking data and making each fundamental type atomic will not make your code correct after threading it.  It eliminates race conditions (in the formal C++ sense, ie UB), but doesn't make things correct.

It is like solving use after free by making everything a shared ptr.  Sure, one problem goes away, but that wasn't the hard part.

Nothing about being in a class makes atomic break.  They work; they don't solve every threading problem.